# Use RK4 method to solve an initial value problem

Tags: differential-equations

I have tried:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 + y^3, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

and did not work, and I have not figured out how to use RK4 order method to find y(2.2), using h = 0.1

Comment: It seems that there are singular point before 2.2 . `sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^3, y[1] == 1}, y[x], {x, 1, 3}, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}]`

Comment: It is done for you in the docs, [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html#1701730745).  @cvgmt That order-4 RK is different than the one most people mean by RK4.